# how to disable an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    <form id="QandA" action="<?php echo htmlentities($action); ?>" method="post">

    <table id="question">

    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <a onclick="return plusbutton();">
    <img src="Images/plussign.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt="Look Up Previous Question" class="plusimage" id="mainPlusbutton" name="plusbuttonrow"/>
    </a>
    <span id="plussignmsg">(Click Plus Sign to look up Previous Questions)</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>


    </form>
```

In the code above I am able to replace an image with another image when the if statement is met. But my problem is that when the image is replaced, it does not disable the on click event. My question is that when the image is replaced, how do I disable the onclick event `onclick="return plusbutton();`?

Comment: `this.onclick=""` is what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You disable from within the `plusbutton` function itself. First, pass the element into the function, like so:

```
<a onclick="return plusbutton(this);">
```

Then disable it in the function:

```
function plusbutton(element) {
    element.onclick = '';
    /* then do whatever plusbutton did before */
}
```

But since you are using jQuery, it's better to use handlers. So give the link an id but not an onclick, like this:

```
<a id="plusbutton" href="#">
```

And use [jQuery.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to bind a click handler that happens just once:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#plusbutton').one('click', function(ev) {
        plusbutton();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I updated code in question, I tried your jquery theory but it hasn't disabled the click. Please look at the updated code so you can hopefully see whats wrong

Comment: Well, you haven't said where your javascript code is defined. Most likely you have to put the click handler in a document.ready block. I updated my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: Also, just noticed you have a `$('.plusimage').live('click', ...` handler. Why? Remove that, that will make it never get removed.

Comment: *Also*, I noticed that your plusbutton method takes in a parameter `plus_id` -- you haven't explained what that's for, and your original code did not use it.

Comment: I need the `$('.plusimage').live('click', ...` function, I think it is better if I do it the non jquery way, because I don't want the # to appear at end of the url, if I do it the non jquery way then what do I need to do to get it working that way?

Comment: Its gonna take a while to get the application set up, the jquery code you provided works but I do not want a # tag at end of url, it messes the navigation. Is there a way I can simply just add the id next to the on click even and then use the id to unbind the click?

Answer (score 1):

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Will prevent the element from proceeding its normal function.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
$('#addQuestionBtn').bind("click",function(){
    $('#addQuestionBtn').unbind("click");   
    insertQuestion(document.form);
});
```

And your html:

```
<input id="addQuestionBtn" name="addQuestion" type="button" value="Add Question" />
```

Comment: You are attaching the event to a different element than the OP had it on. Also, better to just use jQuery.one instead of binding/unbinding.

Comment: yes in this case jQuery.one is the besto solution.. Thanks for the comment. I'm not usually use .one but in this case is the best solution. +1 at your answer @BenLee